# XAML WPF Vertical Scroll bar line by line instead of group by group when grouping

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollbar

What I want to do is scrolling line by line instead of group by group when my items in listview are grouped and I press down/up arrow button of vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem and found this post to see if there was an answer. I finally found a solution to the problem. I wrote my own ControlTemplate for the ListView control and I didn't add the following trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
     <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
</Trigger>
```

So apparently, if you set the ScrolLViewer.CanContentScroll property to false, it will work like a charm. Seems counter-intuitive, but it worked for me. If you post more code, maybe we could help you more.